# autocite similar to autoref / cref?

Tags: citing

When a paper has one author, one can say "see the work of Jackson [1]".
When a paper has two authors, one has to mention them both, i.e., "see the work of Jackson and Muller [2]". For more than two authors, one has to mention the first by name, and the rest captured in "et al.", as in "Jackson et al. [1]".

I am looking for an automated way to achieve this. For instance, now my code will have

```
Jackson~et~al.~\cite{the-citation-id}
Jackson~and~Muller~\cite{the-citation-id}
Jackson~et~al.~\cite{the-citation-id}
```

for the respective cases above. What I would like to be able to do instead, would be to use some macro `\clevercite{the-citation-id}` in all cases.

Comment: Use `natbib` or `biblatex` and tune the style?

Comment: `\textcite` in Biblatex or `\citet` in `natbib`?